# Python - iterate over two object lists and get the parent instances name

Tags: python, loops

First please see the following example code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.folder = 'some/path/'
        self.files = ['name1.txt', 'name2.txt', 'name3.txt']

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.folder = 'somewhere/else/'
    def locals(self):
        b1 = 'name4.txt'
        b2 = 'name5.txt'
        return [b1, b2]

aa = A()
bb = B()

for objname, filename in chain(*[aa.files, bb.locals()]):
    print(filename, objname, objname.folder)
```

*The loop does not work, but is only to point towards, what I am looking for...*

Is there a way to iterate over the two lists and acquire the item's respective folder during iteration?

Speaking in terms of the above example, I'd hope for the following:

```
'name1.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'
'name2.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'
'name3.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'
'name4.txt', 'B()', 'somewhere/else/'
'name5.txt', 'B()', 'somewhere/else/'
```

The different structure of `aa.files` and `bb.locals()` is on purpose and cannot be changed.

Obviously, I could (and am currently doing so) loop through `aa.files` first and do the same loop on `bb.locals()` afterwards, but there is probably a more elegant solution?!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What would you want the loop to print, and what is it actually printing?

Comment: @ShayNehmad: I did made some edits - hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

for (obj,fname) in chain(zip(repeat(aa),aa.files),zip(repeat(bb),bb.locals())):
    print (f"{repr(fname)}, '{'A()' if isinstance(obj,A) else 'B()'}', {repr(obj.folder)}")
```

**Output:**

```
'name1.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'
'name2.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'
'name3.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'
'name4.txt', 'B()', 'somewhere/else/'
'name5.txt', 'B()', 'somewhere/else/'
```

*Update (Robert)* - **Suggestion to shape the solution more to my needs**

```
for (obj,fname) in chain(zip(repeat(aa),aa.files),zip(repeat(bb),bb.locals())):
    print (f"{repr(fname)}, {obj.__class__.__name__}, {repr(obj.folder)}")
```

Principally, I only need to access obj again. Thanks for this solution!!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be to define the `__iter__` method for both like such:

```
class A:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for file in self.files:
            yield file, 'A()', self.folder
    ...

class B:
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for file in self.locals():
            yield file, 'B()', self.folder
    ...

# Example usage
list(A())
# [('name1.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'), ('name2.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/'), ('name3.txt', 'A()', 'some/path/')]

list(B())
# [('name4.txt', 'B()', 'somewhere/else/'), ('name5.txt', 'B()', 'somewhere/else/')]
```